# Create Image Album Group By Month and Year and Show First Image of the Album

Tags: image, laravel, group-by, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am creating an Image Album Grouped by date,

In my Blog App, Every post has a featured Image and I want to create an album of an image that is group by Year and month and show the first image of the album as the album cover, I already grouped my post by date but the problem is I can't get the first image of the album to be the cover of the album

Here is how I grouped by blog post by date

```
$postdates = App\Post::select(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) year, MONTH(created_at) month, MONTHNAME(created_at) month_name, COUNT(*) post_count'))
            ->groupBy('year')
            ->groupBy('month')
            ->orderBy('year', 'desc')
            ->orderBy('month', 'desc')
            ->limit(12)
            ->get();
    ?>
```

and Here is how i get the Image
the problem is I think in here

```
@foreach($postdates as $postdate)
   <li><a href="#"><img src="{{asset('images/'. $postdate->featured_image)}}" alt=""></a></li>
@endforeach
```

"featured_image" is the column of the table for the image names.

Comment: what do you get when you `dd($postdates)` or `dd($postdate)` ? do you recieve data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already got it guys, thanks

```
 $postdates = App\Post::select(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) year, MONTH(created_at) month, MONTHNAME(created_at) month_name, COUNT(*) post_count, MIN(featured_image) as image'))
            ->groupBy('year')
            ->groupBy('month')
            ->orderBy('year', 'desc')
            ->orderBy('month', 'desc')
            ->limit(12)
            ->get();
```